# R - Populate one data frame with values from another dataframe, based on row matching

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace values in myDF1 from myDF2, where rows match for column **"studyno"** but the solutions I have found so far don't seem to be giving me the desired output.

Below are the data.frames:

```
myDF1 <- structure(list(studyno = c("J1000/9", "J1000/9", "J1000/9", "J1000/9", 
"J1000/9", "J1000/9"), date = structure(c(17123, 17127, 17135, 
17144, 17148, 17155), class = "Date"), pf_mcl = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016)), .Names = c("studyno", 
"date", "pf_mcl", "year"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

myDF2 <- structure(list(studyno = c("J740/4", "J1000/9", "J895/7", "J931/6", 
"J609/1", "J941/3"), pf_mcl = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("studyno", 
"pf_mcl"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

One solution I tried that seemed to work is shown below, however, I find that whatever values were in myDF1 before have been removed.

```
myDF1$pf_mcl <- myDF2$pf_mcl[match(myDF1$studyno, myDF2$studyno)]
```

Comment: Can you clarify the output you want, & how your proposed solution differs? It seems to me that if you want to "replace values in myDF1 from myDF2", then the "values [that] were in myDF1 before" *should* "have been removed", so I think I'm missing something.

Comment: You should look into the `merge` function.

Comment: Hi @gung, sorry for not being clear. myDF2 is a subset of myDF1, however, myDF2 is better curated that myDF1. For that reason, I have found some rows in myDF1 have missing values and I am therefore looking for a match in myDF2 and updating those values in myDF1. However, I don't want to loose the values in rows that don't match, which is what the script I posted was doing. Let me know if I need to add more detail.

Comment: Hi, @Kelli-Jean, an example please. I have seen some solutions with the merge function and still wasn't getting the right output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Merge myDF1 & myDF2 by the "studyno", keeping all the rows in myDF1
agg_df = merge(myDF1, myDF2, "studyno", all.x=TRUE)
# Populate pf_mcl in the merged dataframe by using pf_mcl in myDF2 if it is available. Otherwise, use pf_mcl from myDF1
# is missing in myDF1
agg_df$pf_mcl = ifelse(is.na(agg_df$pf_mcl.y), agg_df$pf_mcl.x, agg_df$pf_mcl.y)
myDF1 = agg_df[, names(myDF1)]
```

Comment: Hi @Kelli-Jean, thanks for the solution, pardon my explanation...let me elaborate further. As I mentioned earlier, myDF2 is a well curated subset of myDF1. Therefore, some rows in the two datasets match based on "studyno", you may find that values are missing in myDF1$pf_mcl or the values are wrong. All I want to do is identify a matching row in myDF2 and populate myDF1$pf_mcl with the value in myDF2$pf_mcl. If a row does not match, the value should remain the same. I don't know whether it's worth mentioning, the two data frames have other columns...I have selected a few for example purposes

Comment: @K.Wamae I updated my answer. If this is still not the answer you are expecting, can you provide a data set that has records where your solution is not working? And the expected output. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @Kelli-Jean, I have tested it and it works perfectly. Thank you big time for the solution...